# What is the name for the mathematical property involving addition or subtraction of fractions over a common denominator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

For any number $x$ where $x\in\Bbb R$ and where $x\ne0$, what is the mathematical property which states that:
$${1-x^2\over x} = {1\over x} - {x^2\over x}$$

Comment: Distributivity of division over subtraction? Also, you may want $x\neq 0$.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add that. I’m looking for a concrete or published source on this topic for an argument, but I will take what I can get.

Comment: Why is the tag "discrete mathematics" used here?

Answer (score 1):

Just the computation rules for fractions:
$$
\frac{a - b}{c} = \frac{a + (-b)}{c}  \\
\frac{a + b}{c} = \frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{c} \\
\frac{(-b)}{c} = -\frac{b}{c}
$$
for $a = 1$, $b = -x^2$ and $c = x \ne 0$.

Answer (score 0):

In $\Bbb R$ (or any other [division ring](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisionAlgebra.html)), note that $\frac{x}{y} = x y^{-1}$, where $y^{-1}$ is defined as the number such that $yy^{-1}=1=y^{-1}y$, and $x-y = x + (-y)$, where $-y$ is defined as the number such that $y+(-y)=0=(-y)+y$, and that $(x+y)z = xz + yz$ (multiplication is left-distributive over addition)

So, in any context in which $b$ has an additive inverse, $c$ has a multiplicative inverse, and multiplication is left-distributive over addition, the expression becomes:

$$\frac{a-b}{c} = (a + (-b))c^{-1} = ac^{-1} + (-b)c^{-1} = \frac{a}{c} - \frac{b}{c}$$

Note that $0$ cannot have a multiplicative inverse, so this is true only when $c\ne0$